# How do I convert this query in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

can someone help me please how can I conver this to db query in laravel

```
select a.extn
from access as a
where not exists( select * from users as u where u.accesskey= a.accesskey)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your model name for access table is Access :

```
$result = Access::select('extn')->whereNotIn('accesskey', User::select('accesskey')->toArray());
```